# How to plug in logic (program) in Django. The database is set up and working

Tags: python, django, database, python-2.7, django-1.8

My database has two fields and multiple records. The admin will select any two records and I need to compute the logical 'AND' value of the second field those records. I need to do this for all the combinations selected by the admin. And I need to keep repeating this every 5 mins.

Question 1: Where should I write my logic to do this? (I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 2.7.10)

Question 2 (Optional): How to automate this to run every 5 secs?

Comment: Can you either provide the relevant models or an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, I have the database and everything set up in Django. I'm also able to pull data and all using the python command line.

The question i'm having is where should I write my python logic code?

The code consists of a for loop and an api call. Where to write this code and how to 'plug it' with my web app?

Please help.